# Extracting a sequence from an array

Tags: java, arrays, sequence, extract

I am writing code that reads an integer array in from a file, checks for an increasing sequence of numbers, and prints the length of the array as well as the sequence of numbers itself. The code I have written appears to correctly print the array, showing that is has found the array in the file, and count off the longest sequence of numbers, but it doesn't quite get the exact sequence right. Below is the code in its entirety and the output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner s = null;
    final int MAX_SIZE = 100;
    int count = 0;
    int[] tempArray = new int[MAX_SIZE];
    try {
        s = new Scanner(file);
        int arrayAddress = 0;
        System.out.println("File found!");
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            count++;
            tempArray[arrayAddress] = s.nextInt();
            arrayAddress++;
        }
        s.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException noFile) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }

    int[] inputArray = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        inputArray[i] = tempArray[i];
    }

    int sequence = 0;
    int maxSequence = 0;
    int sequenceEnd = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        for (int k = j; k < count - 1; k++) {
            if (inputArray[k + 1] == inputArray[k] + 1 ) {
                sequence++;
                sequenceEnd = k;
            }
            if (sequence > maxSequence) {
                maxSequence = sequence;
                sequence = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    int temp = 0;
    System.out.println("The array is: " + Arrays.toString(inputArray));
    System.out.println("The longest sequence of increasing numbers is " + maxSequence);
    System.out.println("The sequence is as follows: ");
    for (int i = sequenceEnd - maxSequence; i < sequenceEnd; i++) {
        temp = inputArray[i];
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

The output for the code above on my sequence was as follows:

```
File found!
The array is: [7, 2, 13, 4, 5, 18, 11, 1, 20, 17, 15, 10, 19, 8, 16, 12, 6, 14, 9, 3]
The longest sequence of increasing numbers is 2
The sequence is as follows: 
2
13
```

I really hope this isn't a minor oversight, but I can't seem to figure out where I have made an error. Thanks in advance if you have time to look over this and assist me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

**(1) Finding the maximum length of the sequence**

Your reset of the sequenc length

if (sequence > maxSequence) {
       maxSequence = sequence;
       sequence = 0;
   }

should not be located within the inner loop. That is the one, where you are still counting the elements. You want to move it to the outer loop, i.e. from

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    for (int k = j; k < count - 1; k++) {
    //current location
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    for (int k = j; k < count - 1; k++) {
    }
    //assumingly desired location
}
```

**(2) Print sequence**

The offset of your print-loop is off by one element and should be

```
for (int i = sequenceEnd - maxSequence1; i < sequenceEnd; i++) {
    temp = inputArray[i-1];
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Once `maxSequence` contains the correct amount of elements (i.e. not 2 as it is currently the case), it will print the entire sequence.

Comment: I apologize for any misunderstands that the insufficient explanation must have caused, but the sequence of numbers I need to extract are increasing by an increment of 1. So for the array above, my program was supposed to print 4 and 5. Your changes worked perfectly for increasing series, but I still cannot get the program to print only changes by 1.